# How do I correctly add a visual studios project to a Git repository

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, gitignore

I have already committed my whole Visual Studios project to my Git repository. However, I realized that I didn't include a gitignore file until after I committed my project. I think this is causing problems since I've pushed some of the files that are compiled. My main problem is that my `gitignore` is not ignoring files such as `.dll` and `.pdb`.

How can I fix this? Should I remove my whole project and recommit with the new `gitignore`? or are there specific visual studios folders I can just remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.gitignore` ignores only those files which are not being already tracked with git. Since you already added the `.dll` files, they won't be ignored on their own now.

You can remove specific folders/files from your repo using `git rm`

```
git rm -r --cached folder_1
git rm -r --cached folder_2
git rm --cached file_1
git commit -m "removing unwanted files"
```

The `-r` above is for recursive removal of folders.

However, that will leave a commit history having all those files.

So, if you haven't pushed it upstream already, and have made fairly low number of commits till now, I would recommend creating a new repo - Delete the `.git` folder, and then run `git init`, then create/update the `.gitignore` file with the right entries, and finally add your code again.

Comment: on an aside note, do you know if have duplicate file names in a gitignore will cause problems?

Comment: @RDoolabh  no it shouldn't cause any problems, but why do you want to do that?

Comment: ok great. I just wanted to double-check since once of the files I added to my gitignore may have been ignored under the eclipse section of the gitignore. and your instructions above worked like a charm for ignoring my .dll and .pdb files

Comment: @RDoolabh Cool then ! :)